# NSDateFormatter encoding vs decoding is not consistent

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

When I use this date formatter, it's not giving me back the same date I start with if I got from date -> string -> date.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, YYYY hh:mm aaa"];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSDate *resultingDate = [formatter dateFromString:string];
```

My test generated a date string of `Aug 24, 2010 01:00 PM`.  When fed back into `dateFromString` I get `2009-12-27 13:00:00`.  The time is correct, but the date is all wrong.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this statement:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, YYYY hh:mm aaa"];
```

Change that to this (lowercase y):

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy hh:mm aaa"];
```

And it works fine.

I honestly do not know what is wrong with the code behind the `NSDateFormatter`, but all i know is that it works.

Comment: You are awesome.  Thank you.  I still find it strange that it working fine for date->string, but not string->date.